# Best practice for background task execute at fixed interval of 10 minutes

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I have an app for managing employees and need to track their location at fixed interval of 10 minutes during work hours
what is the best solution for this work manager,services or job scheduler
i already tried services but when app is forced close it doesn't run and lose employee location

Comment: With modern Android version you'll need to use ForegroundService and the user needs to turn off power saving optimizations for your app to reliably track the device location in the background and with the screen off etc. GPS won't work indoors and network based location will be very inaccurate.

Comment: there are supposed to visit customers in their places like home or work i don't need it very accurate  but i'll try foreground service

Answer (score 1):

For tracking location periodically,

**Approximately for X mins - Recommended way** :

1. Use [Fused Location provider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) and set time appropriately. It gives you location update callbacks frequently and is Android's recommended way of getting location. Set your interval using [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long))
2. Ensure you have location permission. Invoke location permission dialog if you don't have permission

**Exact for X mins**

3. Use sticky foreground service to track location continuously without your app getting killed. Check sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)

See Example below

For Fused Location provider

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (requestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```

Create your location request parameters as below :

```
protected static LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {

            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL_MINS * 60 * 1000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_FATEST_TIME_INTERVAL_MINS * 60 * 1000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            return mLocationRequest;
        }
```

Check detailed documentation for Receive periodic location updates [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#java)

Posting from Commonsware [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269429/1300813) here : 
When doing stuff periodically in the background — JobScheduler, WorkManager, AlarmManager, FCM push messages, etc. — you have to take into account that your process might not be around when it is time for you to do your work. Android will fork a process for you, but it is "starting from scratch". Anything that your UI might have set up in memory, such as a database, would have been for some prior process and might not be set up in the new process.

Comment: I need to do it in background so  i keep tracking employees during work hours

Comment: For an app to continuously run in background, you need to use a sticky service. Did you check detailed documentation for Receive periodic location updates https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#java

Comment: I have created background service but i have power consumption problem

Comment: please describe your exact problem with relevant code

Comment: When i run the app on my device after some while i get app is using batter warning 
that warning happened only after i added the background service 

service code : https://gist.github.com/IslamAssem/663c9d1185e69d23b629fdc841ffd0c4
timer class :https://gist.github.com/IslamAssem/507de588affb2bf237384979d6a00cd0
the batter drain warning is very annoying and i need to get rid of it